# How to add dir='rtl' to html tag in angular application

Tags: angular

I am trying to build a multi-lingual application. I am also using angular internationalization. I can use `i18n-dir` to add dir `rtl` and `ltr` based on locale to the root component.

But I want to know how can I add this to `html` tag in `index.html` because not every element will be inside root component. Sometimes we attach elements to body also.

Comment: `Sometimes we attach elements to body also.` Why? You can just get html element like so: `document.documentElement` and add the tag to it.

Comment: I have the same issues how to add dir=" RTL" when Angular - Internationalisation

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for adding the `dir` attribute dynamically. Instead create separate build per language and change the tag in the build phase.